# how to get mime type of a file,which has dot in the file name on android

Tags: android, mime-types, filenames, android-file

i get mime type of a file using the following code:

```
    private String getMimeType(String url) {

        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        Log.e("extension ", extension);

        if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }

   where url is the absolute file path

    i am getting file and folder by the following way
    File file_arr [];
    file_arr = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()).listFiles();
    url = file_arr[i].getAbsolutePath();
```

this is working correct but it **return always null  for which file has dot " . "** in its file name.

for the example

if the file name is **picture1.jpg** then the getMimeType() return **image/jpeg**

in the case of file name has dot (.) in its name for the example **27-05-2012 22.05.14.jpg** then the getMimeType() return null.

i have renamed the file to 27-05-2012.jpg, its return image/jpeg.

my question how to get mime type for all types of file name(which is has dot or special character) on android? please help me.

Comment: what is the value returned by MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url) when you have dots in file name? If everything from the first dot then try to parse extension yourself.

Comment: @murali_ma Problem is with empty space , if you eliminate it will work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this:

```
File f = new File(file);
System.out.println(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
```

Or

```
   if(url.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
    String ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
   } else {
    String type = null;
   }
```

Comment: Don't forget to check if lastIndexOf != -1.

Comment: Thanks @TamásSzincsák for poiting it out :)

Comment: The 1st answer threw a TypeCast exception but the 2nd answer just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getMimeType(String url) {

    String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            fileExtension);
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "FileExtension: " + fileExtension + "\n" + "MimeType: "
                    + mimeType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return mimeType;
}
```

Problem is with space in between your file name , try this code for getting mime type for any file that is having ( "." , "-" , "_" )etc...

Try with this even it will work : **27-05-20.....1222.05.14.jpg**

Comment: This does not work for file names with spaces in them.  fileExtension is null.